# Adding temporary column to table inside PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The idea is that I have one column `Amount` which holds both negative and positive numbers. I would like to calculate `Balance` for each row that will have the the previous amount plus the value inside `Amount` for example

```
| Amount |   | Balance | 
+--------+   |---------+
|   +5   |   |     5   | -- Initial balance should be 0
|   +100 |   |   105   |
|   -10  |   |    95   |
```

What I would like to ask is what should be the method or the algorithm used to calculate `Balance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a cumulative sum:

```
select amount, sum(amount) over (order by ??)
from t;
```

The `??` is for the column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, for a cumulative sum, you need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Indeed 'Cumulative sum' was the term I was looking for, totally forgot about the name of this term, thanks